# Cannot Persist Further Operations After Rolling Back a Dry Run Transaction

Tags: mysql, laravel, transactions, laravel-artisan

I have an artisan command, in which I am cleaning up some data which has gone bad. Before I actually delete the data, I want to do a dry run and show some of the implications that deleting that data may present.

The essesnce of my command is:

```php
    public function handle()
    {
        ...

        $this->dryRun($modelsToDelete); // Prints info to user

        if ($this->confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?') {
            $modelsToDelete->each->forceDelete();
        }
        ...
    }

    public function dryRun($modelsToDelete)
    {
        ...

        DB::connection($connection)->beginTransaction();
        $before = $this->findAllOrphans($models);

        $modelsToDelete->each(function ($record) use ($bar) {
            $record->forceDelete();
        });

        $after = $this->findAllOrphans($models);
        DB::connection($connection)->rollBack();

        // Print info about diff
        ...
    }
```

The problem is that when I do the dry run, and confirm to delete, the actual operation is not persisting in the database. If I comment out the dry run and do the command, the operation does persist. I have checked `DB::transactionLevel()` before and after the dry run and real operation, and everything seems correct.

I have also tried using `DB::connection($connection)->pretend(...)`, but still the same issue. I also tried doing `DB::purge($connection)` and `DB::reconnect($connection)` after rolling back.

Does anyone have any thoughts as to what is going on?

(Using Laravel `v6.20.14`)

Comment: any luck with DB::connection($connection)->transaction(function() {})

Comment: No luck there either @ChinhNguyen

Comment: you sure your code pass the dryRun check

Comment: I am not sure what you mean @ChinhNguyen? I know for a fact the dry run executes and shows me the diff. But then If I select to actually delete, it will not truly be deleted.

If I run the command without the dry run, it will actually delete it.

Comment: i don't know reason yet but i found a way to resolve your problem. when call dryRun pass a deep copy of $modelsToDelete object, example: $this->dryRun(unserialize(serialize($modelsToDelete)));. i guess it's beacause after call forceDelete(), model won't query delete again in future (just guessing)

Comment: Thanks @ChinhNguyen! I will investigate and if it works out, please create an answer and I will award the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after digging the source code, I found out that laravel set property "exists" to false after you call delete on model instance and it will not perform delete query again. you can reference:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9edd46fc6dcd550e4fd5d081bea37b0a43162165/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1173
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9edd46fc6dcd550e4fd5d081bea37b0a43162165/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1129

and to make model instance can be deleted after dryRun, you should pass a deep copy to dryRun, for example:

```
$this->dryRun(unserialize(serialize($modelsToDelete)));
```

note: don't use [php clone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) because it's create a shallow copy

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn on MySQL's "General log".
2. Run the experiment that is giving you trouble.
3. Turn off that log.

The problem may be obvious in the log; if not show us the log.

Comment: My focus is a little split right now, I will get some logs up soon. Thanks for the advice.